# Adding plane and objects in Blender

Tags: objects

[image: this is the plane]

What is the reason when I added a plane the green and red line wont appear at the middle top of the plane
[image: other mesh]
But when  I added other objcts like a cube there are the red and green line in the middle
[image: yt video]
I have watched some videos and Ive been wondering why,when they added a plane there are the green and red line. While mine is different

I just start using blender last 2 weeks and I am a begginner. I hope you guys will be able to answer my question. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, why? Those X,Y axes should be there it the plane is in zero height (`z == 0`)

Comment: HikariTW,  do I need to change the height. How?

Comment: Just move the plane in z axis a little bit down and you can see those lines :)

Comment: Thank you for answering!